# Drools and Maps compilation error

Tags: drools

MY rule condition and action is defined as below. I am getting compilation error. In rule condition I am specified the left and right values as 'abc' and 'xyz'
 which values are stored in a MAP of Me object. When I am using the me.getVariableValues('abc') in action part then its working fine. But, when
I want to use same me.getVariableValues('abc') in condition then I am getting below compilation error.

Error while creating rule package - [139,0]: unknown:139:0 mismatched token: [@463,2378:2383='me',<7>,139:0]; expecting type RIGHT_PAREN[140,37]: 
unknown:140:37 Unexpected token ')'[140,39]: unknown:140:39 Unexpected token 'abc'

rule "rule"

when

me: Me()

getValue(me.getVariableValues(),${condition.leftVariableCode}) ${condition.operator} 
getValue(me.getVariableValues(),${condition.rightVariableCode})

then

me.addVariableValue("$action.output.variableCode", me.getVariableValue("$action.firstInput.VariableCode") $action.operator 
me.getVariableValue("$action.secondInput.VariableCode"));

end

Comment: Absolutely broken syntax starting with "getValue". It looks like some templating code. - What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Laune, thanks for immediate response, Here I am trying to compare the values in a Map based on the condition   defined in rule. DRL string generation is defined in velocity file. The map saved in memory and I want to two values of map.  please let me know give me sample code two compare two values in a map.

Comment: The DRL code as shown is absolutely broken. Where is the Map? How is class Me defined?

Comment: Here is the class Me                                            public class Me{

 

 // Variable Details
 Map<String, Integer> variableValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 public Map<String, Integer> getVariableValues() {
  return variableValues;
 }
public void addVariableValue(String variableCode, Integer count){
  if (count < 0) count = 0;
  this.variableValues.put(variableCode, count);
 }
 public Integer getVariableValue(String variableCode){
  Integer value = this.variableValues.get(variableCode);
  return value == null? 0 : value;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

A correct rule with the given declaration of class Me would be

```
Me( $vv: variableValues )
Map( this["key"] == 42 ) from $vv
```

or

```
Me( $vv: variableValues )
Map( this["foo"] < this["bar"] ) from $vv
```

If you have posted a velocity template, then it is broken.

If you have posted the result after expanding a template, both the template and your expansion mechanism are broken.

Comment: Thanks Laune                                                       result of expanding template is below one--->                          me: Me()
getValue(me.getVariableValues(),Y1PC) > getValue(me.getVariableValues(),Y0CC)